# Detect if Compliance BCC Email is enabled

Tags: apex, email, exception, singleemailmessage

### Problem:

If the Compliance BCC Email setting is enabled email messages cannot be sent with custom BCC addresses e.g.

```
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage toSend = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
toSend.setToAddresses(new List<string>(){'abe@example.com'});
toSend.setBccAddresses(new List<string>(){'bee@example.com'});
// this will fail with BCC_NOT_ALLOWED_IF_BCC_COMPLIANCE_​ENABLED
Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[]{ toSend });
```

### Goal:

I would like to be able to detect if this setting is set so I can prevent BCC addresses from being set.

### What I've done so far:

Googling has thus far only led me to the [documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_sendemail.htm) which gives no real pointers on this. If it's not possible there is always the possibility of just doing a test email that will detect the issue however I'm hoping to avoid that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can send a test message with no parameters, and check the resulting error code. BCC Compliance is checked before other validations, so this should be reliable.

```
Boolean bccComplianceEnabled;
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage m = new messaging.singleEmailmessage();
m.bccsender = true;
try {
Messaging.sendEmail(new messaging.singleemailmessage[] { m });
} catch(emailexception e) {
    bccComplianceEnabled = e.getDmlType(0) == StatusCode.BCC_NOT_ALLOWED_IF_BCC_COMPLIANCE_ENABLED;
}
```

Note that the email won't be sent, because we do not specify a target address or any other values; BCC compliance is checked before any other tests.

Comment: I updated the code with a new version I tested in my Developer Edition. This should be reliable, as far as I can tell.

Comment: While I was hoping to avoid this pattern it seems the only viable solution unless salesforce exposes the setting.

Comment: If there is, I'd love to know about it. Having been with salesforce.com technical support for years, I've learned that hacks are quite frequently necessary to work with salesforce.com. Granted, it's still a far better platform compared to most others I've experienced...