# Detect System Email Only

Tags: email

I have a full sandbox where Deliverability has been set to `System Email Only`. I already know how to change this to `All Email` but we have other reasons for not doing this (mainly we appreciate the extra safety since real user data has been cloned to the full sandbox).

I have APEX code that sends single email messages to administrators (notify that a job is done, etc). This of course throws this error:

```
NO_MASS_MAIL_PERMISSION, Single email is not enabled for your organization or profile.
```

I'll probably end up wrapping this in a try/catch to eat the error gracefully, but I wonder if there is a way to detect the System Email Only setting in code?

I had hoped that `Limits.getLimitEmailInvocations()` would return `0` in my sandbox but it returns `10`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exceptions are indeed the proper way to detect this condition. I used a similar method in [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/15867/detect-if-compliance-bcc-email-is-enabled) to detect if BCC compliance is enabled. You'll want to look up the appropriate enum for the error you want to detect, although it should match the uppercase error code you received.

Comment: Thanks. Comparing the statuscode as you did in your answer is better than my first `getMessage().contains("NO_MASS_MAIL_PERMISSION")` approach.